# jQuery Sparklines more the one graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sparklines

I am trying to show two spark line graphs using jQuery Sparklines but for some reason i only shows me one, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="graphs">
    <span id="sparkline"></span>
    <br>
    <span id="sparkline2>"></span>
</div>


</body>

<script>
    $("#sparkline").sparkline([74.82290216,
        74.82290216,
        48.70129726,
        70.77921869,
        72.07791995,
        69.15584211,
        74.05548778,
        76.91853079,
        70.24792886,
        80.34237956], {
        type: 'line',
        width: '100',
        height: '50'
    });

    $("#sparkline2").sparkline([74.82290216,
        74.82290216,
        48.70129726,
        70.77921869,
        72.07791995,
        69.15584211,
        74.05548778,
        76.91853079,
        70.24792886,
        80.34237956], {
        type: 'line',
        width: '100',
        height: '50'
    });

</script>
</html>
```

As you can see i have two spans with two different id's and still i get only the first one.
I even tried to load to the same span but it makes no difference.
Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in your 2nd span.  Check the ".  With that fixed it works https://jsfiddle.net/blaird/jsLwqmLh/

Comment: I have tried also to load the two line into one div with no success can you maybe help with that as well?

Comment: Please ask a separate question if you have a new question. Nobody sees follow-up questions asked in the comments.